# C++/CX way of iterating Map<String^, Object^>^?

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, c++-cx

I have a object of type of `Map<String^, Object^>^`. How do I iterate in C++/CX way? I am trying to use iterator but I am not clear about syntax. Documentation doesn't provide an example.

Comment: it is C++/CX (Windows Store apps). I have the type IMap<String^, Object^> and its iterator takes some IKeyValuePair type. I am not familiar with C++ much, so this is hard to figure out given that no examples were given.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

C++/CX collections follow the same principles as c++ collections, so they have iterators and begin, end functions.

```
IMap<Platform::String^, Platform::Object^>^ map = ref new Map<Platform::String^, Platform::Object^>();
map->Insert("key1", "val1");
map->Insert("key2", 2.0f);

// Exactly like you would iterate over a map, but instead of std::pair you have IKeyValuePair
std::for_each(begin(map), end(map), [](IKeyValuePair<Platform::String^, Platform::Object^>^ pair)
{
    // do stuff
    auto key = pair->Key;
    auto value = pair->Value;
});

for( auto pair : map )
{
    // do stuff
    auto key = pair->Key;
    auto value = pair->Value;
}
```

Also, don't forget to include collection.h and use namespace Platform::Collections.

Comment: "don't forget to include collection.h" - this is a lifesaver.